# Add an ID to clicked links but remove it from others

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, addition

I am hoping someone can help me with this. The jQuery tabs on my page are using background images and I am trying to add an id="current" to the clicked links (for active status) and want the ID removed from the others. I also want the first tab to have the id when the page opens. Everything that I have tried either removes id="current" from all links, or adds it to all links. Thanks in advance for any help forthcoming. ~c

```
**jQuery**
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

$('#tabs a').click(function(){
$(this).parent().attr('id', 'current');
('li #current').removeAttr('id', 'current');
});

});
</script>



CSS
#tabs a { float:left;background:url(images/tabLeft.png) no-repeat left top;}
#tabs a span { float:left;display:block;background:url(images/tabRight.png) no-repeat  right top;}/*grey bg*/
#tabs #current a { background-position:0% -30px;} /*purple bg*/
#tabs #current a span { background-position:100% -30px;} 

HTML
 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
 <li id="current"><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>Tab 4</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-5"><span>Tab 5</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1" >Tab 1 Content</div>
    <div id="tabs-2" >Tab 2 Content</div>
    <div id="tabs-3" >Tab 3 Content</div>
    <div id="tabs-4" >Tab 4 Content</div>
    <div id="tabs-5" >Tab 5 Content</div>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all, you should use classes to do that, instead of id's.

Comment: You can't have more than one id per element.

Answer (score 1):

First, drop the use of id's for that kind of thing. I made an example, for you to see how you use classes to manipulate the elements and toggle the classes.

```
$('.tab li a').click( function(){
$('.tab li a').parent().find('.current').removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('current');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madaaah/hX4hE/

Comment: I understand about making 'current' a class ... however, the class won't apply to the <li> unless I add the #tab to the css. I cannot get this to work and have tried various different ways to try to traverse through the DOM to accomplish this. I'm quite lost. Here is my code ... any other hints that I can try will be most appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/2VszF/

Comment: I'm not quite undertanding what you need.. Did you check my fiddle for the rest of the code? One important thing is: the .click part of the javascript should go on document.ready. Please explain a little better what you want this tabs to do.

Comment: Check this version, working with Jquery UI to power the tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/madaaah/hX4hE/22/

Comment: madaaah - I need to use the css styles that i have in my jsfiddle example. The tabs are being used in another area of the site (which I took over) and I want them to work in a tab/panel jquery structure. The 'current' class repositions two sprite images, one to the <a> tag, the other to the <span> tag, to make the active tab a different color. So, I am trying to add the 'current' class to the parent li of the a tag with the click event, while removing it from the other tabs, making only one active tab at a time. So the structure I have in place cannot change. Hope this helps make more sense.